# My cat's left eye and his belly don't look right.

Tags: cats, health

Looking very strange.

His left eye is showing signs of redness currently. It's very watery and he seems to be having trouble keeping it open. There's no discharge except the wateriness.

As for his belly, there is a spot on it. Circular and pinkish-red. It looks dry and agitated.

He is not an outdoor cat. He has no fleas and had no ability to get into anything outside. (He's honestly terrified to go outside.) He's not around other cats either.

So far I've been cleaning his eye with a warm cloth. Should I put a little salt on the cloth? He drinks plenty of water and he doesn't appear to be having difficulty rating or being playful. He sleeps most of the day and is active at night. And he's been pooping and peeing regularly, too.

Here is a picture of his belly: 
[image]

And here is a picture of his eyes:
[image]

(He's currently in a playful mood) 
[image]

Comment: I have added the two pictures you had linked in the body and the one in the comments. Thank you for making them available.  I will not be able to answer your question but when one of our cat experts comes by they might like to know how long ago these symptoms occurred.

Answer (score 5):

I would get the eye looked at by a Vet soonest. We had a similar issue with one of our cats and it was basically corneal ulceration. It's uncomfortable and reduces vision and if not treated, can result in loss of sight in the eye. However, if caught and treated reasonably early, a full recovery is a few weeks away.

So, in short, get him in for a look, you've almost perfectly described the symptoms our cat had. Just be prepared to apply various eye drops many times a day.

Comment: John, thanks for your input. I am staying close by Piko so see if anything worsens. A vet is close so I can take him if there is an emergency. Today I noticed that his eye is looking better. He doesn't have nearly as much discharge/wateriness and the spot on his belly is fading out of its redness. We are hoping that the spot was a spider bite of sorts. Piko seems much better, running about and loving on us. I still pay very close attention on him just to be sure.

Comment: Update! Piko's eye seems to have gotten better. The spot on his belly is fading as is his discharge and watery eyes. I do hope this was the problem but I'm watching him closely. c: